# name an existing planar search algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I've implemented an algorithm that takes a field filled with randomly sized, randomly positioned rectangles and divides both the X & Y places into sections cutting along every horizontal and vertical edge of each rectangle and recording a list of what rectangles are in each section.
These two X & Y lists of sections and their corresponding lists of rectangles are then used to determine what rectangle(s) are beneath the mouse cursor at any given point (x, y).

it works great but I don't know what to call it.
this is probably a long existing algorithm that George Boole himself wrote but I don't know the name of it.
[algorithm divides X & Y axes into sub-divisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIuDp.png)

[algorithm divides X & Y axes into sub-divisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIuDp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a precomputed variant of the [sweep and prune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_and_prune) algorithm.

Comment: not sure that's it. there's no pruning involved and nothing is moving.

Comment: Pruning is definitely involved in your algorithm; that's the conjunction step (comparing the two lists and choosing the common elements). Items moving is not a core part of SAP, just common to most SAP use cases.

Comment: Yes, as you would when in the (v2, h4) region in your example, when you excluded A and C. That's what "prune" refers to in SAP.

Comment: yes.  I think you're right.  there's a better article than the Wiki-page [link](http://www.codercorner.com/SAP.pdf ).  thanks for your help